# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv

Tags: java, html, spring, servlets, stream

I'm trying to send a csv from server to client as a stream. The exchange and download works correctly, however, chrome always logs the following in the console:

`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv`

The client request looks like this:

```
<form class="feedbackCSVGenerator" method="get" action="my/url">
    <button type="submit" role="button"><span>Download as CSV</span></button>
</form>
```

And the server side implementation:

```
response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment;filename=Feedback.csv");
response.setContentLength("Hello world".getBytes().length);
try {
    ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outStream.write("Hello world".getBytes());
    outStream.close();
    response.flushBuffer();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //
}
```

Is there a different MIME-type I should choose, or perhaps another response header I can set to keep this message from popping up? It doesn't seem to be affecting anything, but still...

Comment: Could you resolve this issue? if yes, please post your solution. I am facing this same issue.

Comment: No solution yet, but it seems to be harmless.